# Segmentation fault on little function

Tags: c, sorting, segmentation-fault

I keep getting a segmentation fault on this one, does someone see the reason?

```
void str_sort(char s[]) {
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = strlen(s) - 1; i > 0; i--)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (*(s+j) > *(s+j+1)) {
                c = *(s+j);
                *(s+j) = *(s+j+1);
                *(s+j+1) = c;
            }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you passing in a literal string like `str_sort("abc")` or `char str[] = "abc"; str_sort(str);`?

Comment: It works now, if I do it like this char str[] = "abc"; str_sort(str); But why?? Thx btw

Comment: So, that would be a 'yes' ;(

Comment: you cant change literals

Answer (score 2):

String literals are stored in a region of memory that disallows modifications. If you create an array to store the string instead, it should work fine (assuming your function is correct which it looked like at first glance):

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "PC-spiel";
    str_sort(str);
    return 0;
}
```

The difference is a string literal like `"PC-spiel"` is a pointer to a non-modifiable constant. But the string `str` is located on the stack like a normal array/variable and gets the value `"PC-spiel"` copied into it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your string sorting function operates in place.  It will modify its string argument. It you call it with a string literal, trying to modify the argument will invoke undefined behavior.  If the string literal is already sorted such as `"abc"`, no problem since no write access is performed, but if you call `str_sort("ba");` undefined behavior ensues and a crash is a possible form of undefined behavior.

Note that you should use the index notation for better readability and the final `return;` is useless:

```
void str_sort(char s[]) {
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = strlen(s) - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (s[j] > s[j+1]) {
                c = s[j];
                s[j] = s[j+1];
                s[j+1] = c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```